# Angular2 - 2 way binding on text box input tag

Tags: angular

This is very simple with angular 1, but somehow I am not able to get it working with Angular 2.

lets say in my component, I have a model - ***myModel.name.title***, and in its constructor I set some value, there is an input of type text (below) in the template which modifies the value :-

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel.name.title" />
<p>{{ myModel | json }}</p> //for previewing
```

But, when I type something in the text box, there is no update in the preview.
Also, when I change the model programmatically, there is no change in the text box.

I am initializing it -

```
@Component({})
export class .... {
   myModel: any;
   constructor(){
     this.myModel = {
        id: uniqid,
        name: {
          title: '',
          styles: {}
        }
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize the `myModel` object this way in the component containing your input:

```
constructor() {
  this.myModel = {
    name: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I am initializing it - like this in the constructor - myModel =  {
        id: uniqid,
        title: {
          string: '',
          styles: {}
        },
      }

Comment: Yes but there is another level with the `name` since you use `myModel.name.title`...

Comment: I got this working, there was some problem with some other tag, and because of it, it was not working -- as after deleting those blocks which were giving console error, it started working.